# how to respond back to Python from an NSNotification?

Tags: python, objective-c

I'm calling into Obj from Python using this code:

```
    print "Login begin";
    nc = Foundation.NSDistributedNotificationCenter.defaultCenter();
    userInfo = NSDictionary.dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys_("7","operation",user,"username",password,"password",None);    
    nc.postNotificationName_object_userInfo_deliverImmediately_(SIMULATOR_NOTIFICATION,"",userInfo,1);
    return;
```

The ObjC receives it thusly:

```
- (void) recievedNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSControl *postingObject = [notification object]; // the object that posted the notification
    NSMutableDictionary *response = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];

    int switcher = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"operation"] intValue];

    switch (switcher) {
```

**My question is: how do I return a value (such as a success/failure boolean) back to my Python code?**

BTW it's not my code, and yes I can see various problems with it, but that dev left and now I've been asked to update it. You know how it is.

Comment: This is, unfortunately for you, a _distributed_ notification, not a regular `NSNotification`. You'll have to do something like post a distributed notification back -- you can't really just "return" a value to another process. If you need a lot of communication back and forth, sockets might be the way to go. There's also [distributed objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html) for really tight interaction.

Comment: Fair enough. How do I do either with Python and ObjC?